# Python Dash App is Not Rendering in Browser

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I tried to run the following example code from https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial but it just gives me a blank browser tab which seems to infinitely load:

```
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello World')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is it blocked by something? How to unblock it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the example work without any changes in code. I also saw infinite time loading of the page "http://127.0.0.1:8050/". After I allowed Javascript, the page loaded successfully showing "Hello World". Maybe you also blocked Javascript or this port 8050?

Comment: how can I unblock both?

Comment: That depends on your operating system / firewall (opening a Port) and your browser (activating Javascript). Enable Javascript in Chrome browser: https://www.howtogeek.com/663569/how-to-disable-and-enable-javascript-on-google-chrome/

Activate a specific Port: https://www.howtogeek.com/394735/how-do-i-open-a-port-on-windows-firewall/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason a simple computer restart did the trick. Now it runs.